# How to mount a DSLR to the ceiling for bird's eye view pictures?

Tags: support-equipment, tripod-socket

I am looking to take pictures of oriental carpets and need to somehow mount my DSLR to the ceiling.  I do have a remote shutter, but I am wondering what would be the best way to mount a DSLR to a ceiling?

The ceiling is like a warehouse type ceiling with steel supports every couple feet.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal approach is to use something like a [Manfrotto Super Clamp](http://www.manfrotto.com/super-clamp-without-stud), perhaps in conjunction with a tripod head (if the clamp itself needs to be attached at an inconvenient angle) and/or a [Magic Arm](http://www.manfrotto.com/magic-arm-with-bracket).

But that's the walk-into-the-camera-store, off-the-shelf solution. You can use any sufficiently secure clamping system (available at most hardware/home improvement stores). Almost all cameras use a standard 1/4"-20 screw to mount to, well, a mount; almost all tripod heads meant for small and medium format cameras use a standard 3/8"-16 screw on the bottom side (where it would normally attach to a tripod). Cobbling something together is pretty easy, and you can use a short piece of aircraft cable as a safety harness, running from the camera's strap loops to the overhead beam/joist/rafter/strut. It's not as versatile and quick to set up on location, but if you're not normally rigging facilities for rempote cameras, it's an awful lot cheaper.

Comment: Excellent answer.  This is the kind of stuff I was looking for.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Joby GorillaPod](http://joby.com/gorillapod), I've heard good things about it but I never used one myself (if you go this way get the original Joby Gorillapod, the knock-offs are generally awful)

Comment: I was thinking about going this route also, but I am wondering how safe it would be.  I have to admit I would be nervous about it falling, but it is worth looking into.

Comment: You can always loop a neck strap over one of the steel trusses and then reattach it to the camera's lugs as a safety strap.